# galaxy s3 mini - notifcation sounds -how to turn off.

Tags: notifications

I have the default notification sounds set to silent but every few minutes a bell sounds. Does anyone know what is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to chase this down.

I would start by checking the notifications bar to see if it will tell you what app is trying to get your attention.

If that doesn't lead you the culprit, take a look through the settings > sound area.  You may have inadvertently turned on screen lock sounds or dialing sounds or keyboard sounds.

If neither of those work, head over to settings > accessibility and look through the options for possibilities.